# verify e-mail send and receive on android

Tags: android, email

We are experiencing intermittent problems receiving ActiveSync e-mail on Android phones.  Samsung recommends restarting the device which works.

Is there an app available that could send an e-mail every hour and receive an automatic reply without user intervention?  If the app detects a problem, the user would receive a notification that e-mail is not working.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You are asking for an app itself or do you want to develop an app with the required functionality?

Comment: As it is, this question is off-topic for SO (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).